# Type mismatch when passing a query parameter to a controller from a template

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm trying to set up a url that allows optional query params. e.g.

```
myurl?number=1
```

I'm getting a compile error when I try to pass a value to my controller from inside of a template.

e.g.

```
<a href="@routes.Application.myView(Option(1))"></a>
```

Where the `routes.conf` is configured as follows:

```
GET    /myurl/            controllers.Application.myurl(number: Option[Int])
```

The specific error is:

```
Type mismatch. Expected Nothing, actual: Option[Int]
```

It works a OK if I hit the URLs directly in the browser. However, if I try to supply the query param in the template, it fails.

---

The above I got from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16301211/handling-freeform-get-url-parameters-in-play-2-routing), which is why I set up my route using option.

```
GET  /foo    controllers.MyController.foo(name: Option[String], age: Option[Int])
```

And...

```
def foo(name: Option[String], age: Option[Int]) = Action { implicit request =>
    Ok(s"Name is: $name, age is $age")
```

---

How do I pass a query param to the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I you have read Reverse Routing in Play framework then it would be easy for you to understand this.

When you are trying to use optional query parameter then, you define your end point as

```
GET    /myurl/            controllers.Application.myurl(number: Option[Int])
```

and you can use it from your template as

```
<a href="@routes.Application.myView(Some(1))"></a>
```

The code will be compiled but your IDE may show you an error ignore the error by IDE and just move on from there.

So, whenever you are calling your action from template using reverse routing then you can use the above calling method and it will be treated by play as `/myrul?number=1` and if you paste this url in your browser then your `myurl` action will be called and number parameter will be treated as option to it.

Like, i am using in one of my application as follows:

## My EndPoint

```
GET         /file/:id                                        @controllers.FileController.getFile(id:String,w:Option[Int],h:Option[Int])
```

## My Template

```
<img src="@controllers.routes.FileController.getFile(company.logoPath,Some(150),None)" />
```

## End point seen on terminal

```
 GET /file/1ecf481b-9fb3-4d9d-93f5-16b10a6cefa3?w=150 took 134ms and returned 200
```

Does that make it clear?