# Overloading a route with dynamic http parts

Tags: url, playframework, get, routes, operator-overloading

I have one route like:

```
GET     /latest/:repo/:artifact     controllers.Find.findLatestArtifact(repo: String, artifact: String)
```

that works as a restful api for us. But now, I have a new view with an html form that need to send actions to that controller filling up the parameters with two html selects from the form.

I have tried adding another route like:

```
GET     /latest     controllers.Find.findLatestArtifact()
```

and overloading the controller method to read the http get parameters manually, but it does not like it.

Previously in the past I already asked here how to fill up parameters from a html form, in a controller that does not have 0 args:

[Binding an html form action to a controller method that takes some parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32722643/binding-an-html-form-action-to-a-controller-method-that-takes-some-parameters)

and seems that it was not possible. Then, how do I workaround this, without having to rename the controller method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**
I've provided an answer to your other question but the clean solution to this is unrelated.
You actually can overload the route with something like

```
GET     /latest                     controllers.Find.findLatestArtifact()
GET     /latest/:repo/:artifact     controllers.Find.findLatestRepoArtifact(repo: String, artifact: String)
```

Make sure they are listed in the correct order. Obviously these will route to different methods (this is cleaner server side and more descriptive to what the method actually does), so in your code you would want a simple redirect or just return the result of the overloaded method:

```
public static Result findLatestArtifact(){
        return findLatestRepoArtifact("DefaultRepo","DefaultArtifact");
}

public static Result findLatestRepoArtifact(String repo, String artifact){
               ... some code here ...
}
```

Or you could do it your other way ([see other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32722643/binding-an-html-form-action-to-a-controller-method-that-takes-some-parameters))