# What is the ?= operator in the Play Framework?

Tags: scala, playframework

I have seen the `?=` operator used for setting default values when defining routes in Play. But I cannot find any references to it the documentation. Where is this operator documented? Is this a Scala thing or a Play Framework thing?

Example Usage:

```
GET  /users  controllers.Application.users(max:java.lang.Integer ?= 50, page:java.lang.Integer ?= 0)
```

(taken from: [How to handle optional query parameters in Play framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9657163/how-to-handle-optional-query-parameters-in-play-framework)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is specific to the Play Framework. It is (briefly) documented in the [routing section](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaRouting#Parameters-with-default-values).

> `conf/routes` is the configuration file used by the router.

The `routes` file is not Scala; it only resembles it.